# Underline on sublinks from navbar

Tags: css, wordpress

I am making a small site. When a link in the navbar is active, there is an underline on the link. Here is "Formidling" active: [Example site][1]. The problem is that when I click fx: "Kurser" in the left sidebar, the underline is disappearing.

I would like that the underline is gonna stay in the menubar when you click on a submenu in the sidebar.

I tried to solve this with the following code, but I think I am going the wrong way?

```
.current-menu-item {
     text-decoration: underline !important;
}

a:active {
    color: #993366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: just add the class ´current-menu-item´ to the active button on every page where it would stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following to your js.

What I did here is add click event to each sidebar link, on click, remove class `current-menu-item` from all sidebar link, then add this `current-menu-item` class to the one you clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.content-sidebar-wrap a').click(function() {
    $('.content-sidebar-wrap a').removeClass('current-menu-item');
    $(this).addClass('current-menu-item');
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer and the code. The problem is that I do not have access to the files on ftp. Can I add this code in the wp-admin somewhere?

Comment: @NekMak take a look at this maybe? I never used WP but there should be a way you can add js code. https://www.godaddy.com/garage/industry/tech-svcs/wordpress/3-ways-to-insert-javascript-into-wordpress-pages-or-posts/